# how to read the mail and display as html format

Tags: php, regex, email

i need to read the mail and display as html format, so that i can use domdocument to extract link from it..

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());


$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');


if($emails) {

        $header = imap_fetchheader($inbox,2);
$message1 = imap_fetchbody($inbox,9,2);
}
```

currently i can read the mail body as text/html content..

how to pass the result from above to domdocument function and retrieve the links in the mail using the below code..

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute( 'href' );
```

the loadhtml function needs a html format content, so can you pls tell me how to read the mail as html format..

Comment: that's about what you'd have to do. did you check if `$message1` is actually the html portion of the mail?

Comment: @Marc B yes it is html portion.. but i could not pass $message1 to loadhtml function..

Comment: dom is **VERY** picky about the html it will accept. make sure it's not rejecting the html because of syntax errors.

Comment: @Marc B so is there any other way to extract links alone from the mail body.. i know we can use regex, but it also needs html format content to process

Comment: fix up the mangled html and then use dom. regexes on html is bad enough. regexes on mangled html is suicidal.

Comment: @Marc B ok sure.. do you have any idea here.. how to read mail as html code and pass it to domdocument.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34477/discussion-between-thuk-and-marc-b)